# How would I pass a id from one ngRepeat to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I'm doing is I have posts ngRepeat and I have another for the comments. I can't get the comments for those posts unless I some how pass the id of the post into the comments ngRepeat.

```
<div ng-app="posts" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
   <div id="posts_container" ng-repeat="post in posts">

    <div id="the_post">


        <!-- I've got to pass the post.id to get the right comments for that post -->
        <div id="the_comments" ng-repeat="comment in comments">

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is simple in php foreach loop to do but I haven't figured it out in angularjs. Also is it good to nest ng-repeat? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it the [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) what you are looking for?

```
<div id="the_comments" ng-repeat="comment in comments | filter:{id:post.id}">
```